# 404 redirect in .htaccess for http and https simultaneously

Tags: .htaccess

Our visitors could browse domain via http and https.

Is there a way to write 404 redirect in .htaccess:

1. all requests via **http** for non-existent pages should be redirected (with 404 header) to: **http**://domain
2. all requests via **htts** for non-existent pages should be redirected (with 404 header) to: **https**://domain

Now we have only one rule in .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://domain
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=302,L]
```

original protocol will be maintained in this redirect.

Comment: anubhava, thank you. but this decision does not work as we expect. Non-existent page is not redirected to the main page of domain. For example, URL "domain/non-existent/page/" must be redirected to URL "domain" with header 404. URL "domain/non-existent/page/" shows header 404 and content of main page of domain but URL "domain/non-existent/page/" is not redirected to URL "domain".

Comment: anubhava, unfortunately it does not work as expects: non-existent pages are not redirected with header 404. As I understand this problem has no solution because it is impossible to use 404 with flag R ([R=404]) in RewriteRule. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Actually `R=404` can be used above but then it won't redirect to home page. You will need little bit of PHP support to achieve this.